# Custom Scroll: How to hide the scrollbar and create a button that will scroll on click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I'm not sure where to start with this, or if it's possible. I have a div that contains text, and when the text is too long to fit in one line, it displays the scrollbar to allow the user to scroll left/right. My client wants to remove the scroll bar (but maintain scrolling functionality) and instead have an arrow that the user can click to scroll. Is this possible with css/jquery, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the

> scrollTop

function from jQuery

```js
$("#scroll").click(function(e) {
    var scrollTop = $('#example').scrollTop();
    $('#example').scrollTop(scrollTop+5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="scroll">scroll</button>
<div id="example" style="width:300px;height:200px;overflow:hidden">
Lorem ipsum sapien ante ut risus, dictum faucibus vehicula interdum proin magna, aliquam interdum sollicitudin tempus. viverra nisl sociosqu curabitur pharetra proin gravida pellentesque, neque felis aliquam ante ullamcorper nisi consectetur, iaculis elementum convallis quis curabitur tincidunt pharetra, platea sagittis euismod cras habitant lorem. torquent congue tortor in tortor vulputate dictumst per, pellentesque luctus sapien dolor eleifend sagittis ullamcorper leo, vulputate senectus eleifend viverra varius quisque. class ligula adipiscing metus primis platea dictumst nibh felis etiam a commodo platea congue vivamus, ultrices proin arcu mollis netus arcu vel fusce libero nostra quisque odio. 

 Non quisque potenti quisque ligula habitant varius porta ultricies nisi sagittis eros, interdum id elit habitasse tincidunt justo libero proin magna velit erat, viverra praesent eget risus nullam suscipit leo amet blandit vestibulum. tempus sodales lacus venenatis aliquam vivamus maecenas potenti, laoreet tempus fusce conubia maecenas scelerisque eros, volutpat praesent vel justo urna erat. nam cursus tincidunt nec placerat aliquam curae class, nulla aenean felis lacinia taciti nullam purus torquent, litora eleifend aenean posuere diam tortor. blandit tempus egestas vulputate primis aenean pretium quis elit et nostra eu, fames iaculis felis elit porta augue ante dapibus ultrices curae, ornare semper id ut nisl fusce congue urna proin non.
</div>
```